# Kong API Gateway Php

Tags: kong

We are currently study about kong API gateway. we know about kongs API authentication and all other things. we not got that how to implement it in php. How we can insert and retrieve data from database and return it through kong API.
ANd if you have any demo than provide us. so we can easily understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You interface Kong via HTTP requests, in PHP that is the http wrapper (at foremost), see: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php - Kong admin REST API (better: 
*HTTP interface*) is compatible with the PHP HTTP wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Kong is API Gateway and it does not give any feature to store values in DB and then retrieve. You have to create APIs (for you in PHP) and add all the functionality to PHP APIs as you wish.

Once you develop working APIs in PHP which will do all the work you are expecting it to do, then Kong will come into picture.

Kong will be used to expose your APIs in controlled fashion. You can add authentication, metering and other features of Kong to the APIs, without having them in PHP APIs.